# as3 TextInput cursor on mouse over

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an application with a custom cursor. I basically hide the default cursor using

```
flash.ui.Mouse.hide();
```

and then I create a cursor using a movie clip that I move around the screen by listening to mouse movements on the stage.

I have a TextInput form on my application. The strange thing is when I use the mouse to hover over the textInput field I get a small bar cursor appear on top of my custom one.

I've tried adding event listeners to ROLL_OUT and ROLL_OVER events to call `Mouse.hide()` again, but I still have this cursor appearing and I can't seem to get rid of it.

Does anyone know what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? `myTextField.selectable = false;`

Comment: Does actually solve the problem, but I need the TextField to be selectable

Comment: I'm afraid you can't hide that cursor then... Can't you make it selectable on click?